# Table Saw without ability to lower blade

Tags: table-saw

I recently received a secondhand saw, a black and decker 9442, and from what I can tell there is no way to adjust the blade height.  All I see is a tilt lever to make angle adjustments.

Am I missing something?

From this web shot of the saw it seems to have a lowered blade so I’m a bit confused...

If this is so, what are my options for using this machine safely?  I’ve read about using 7 1/4 circular saw blades on a table saw and thought it might be my only option apart from having a larger 10” blade exposed all the time.[image]

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think that the hand-wheel that's missing from the silver shaft may function to raise & lower the blade. I tried searching for "black & decker 9442" but all that I could find of use were parts supply places indicating that most of the parts are no longer available. You may want to grab that shaft with a pair of locking pliers and see if turning it will raise/lower the blade. If so, find any sort of knob/wheel that will fit the shaft. Worst case, dedicate a pair of pliers to the task.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the sides if they have any holes or slots there?

Comment: "9442" is the name for a number of B&D band saws, too. Annoying.

Answer (score 8):

The missing part is going to be a handwheel that attaches to the shaft that's about one-third from the left side of the arc cut into the side of the machine.

As it turns, the motor assembly and saw blade will raise and lower as desired. As FreeMan suggests, grab the shaft with pliers, although that will degrade the surface of the shaft. Consider to pad the pliers with a piece of rubber or canvas to protect it.

Additional research found a possible [match on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Black-Decker-5140032-48-Handwheel-/253407374915?_trksid=p2385738.m4383.l4275.c10) but it would be wise to measure the shaft diameter and ask the seller to measure the item for sale. If there is a keyway on the shaft, that would be a factor to discuss with the seller too.

[image: handwheel]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I’ll take a look tonight.

Comment: Used some pliers and gently lowered the blade down.  Need to purchase a handwheel now.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Beat me to it, once I found a likely manual online.

Comment: There should be another handwheel on the side, probably on the right, to tilt the blade.

Comment: The handle above the arc for the blade height adjustment appears to be a locking handle, perhaps suitable for releasing the mount used to tilt the blade.